# command to find words and display columns

Tags: linux, unix, command

I want to search some words in a log file & display only given column numbers from those lines in the file.

eg: i want to search "word" in abc.log and print columns 4,11

```
grep "word" abc.log | awk '{print $4}' | awk '{print $4}'
```

but this doesn't workout  can some one please help

Answer (score 1):

You need to print `$4` and `$11` together rather than piping `$4` into another `awk`.

Also, you don't need `grep` because `awk` can `grep`.

Try it like this:

```
awk '/word/{print $4,$11}' abc.log
```